# Passing out an argument

Tags: string

I can't figure out why `test` is not passed properly to `test1`

```
#include <Arduino.h>

char *test1;
char *status_reply(char *test) {
        int ans_rel = 1;
        int ans_led = 0;
        int ans_sw = 1;
        sprintf(test,"%d%d%d",ans_rel,ans_sw,ans_led);
        Serial.println(test);
}

void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);
        status_reply(test1);
        Serial.println(test1);
}

void loop() {
        // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Comment: While commenting on [an answer to a previous question of yours](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/55400), I suggested you read the section [Arrays and Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/) of the C FAQ. Judging from from this new questions, it seems you failed to do so. _Please, read it!_ Otherwise you will spend lots of time asking here related (and off-topic) questions.

Comment: @EdgarBonet well I did read it. I must say that the main purpose or motivation of declaring a char as char* - is quite unclear

Comment: To be clear- I understand the technicalities of such definitions, but not when or why to use each one of them. It is a whole different from Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not about Arduino. It is C. You have only a pointer to char now. You must allocate memory for the c-string.

`char test1[128];`

If you pass pointer to sprintf, the function will write to memory where the pointer points. Something somewhere in memory will be overwritten and the following print will print the string, but later the memory will be used for something else and your c-string disappear.

Comment: thank you. There's something I'm missing : 1) In any other case if I would init `char *test1="hello world"` at the beginning, and print it `Serial.println(test1)` - I would have get proper value. 2) In code here - when I create `test` inside it does print it as expected, but not passing its value to `test2` ?

Comment: `char *test1="hello world"` would be a pointer to a global allocated constant c-string and should be `const char *test1="hello world"`. I enhanced the answer.